# pthread_mutex_destroy: why is it returning EBUSY?

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, posix

I'm stepping through some code in a third party library that our executable is linked to, specifically the "shutdown" code. I'm sending a SIGQUIT to our application, which shuts down the third party objects.

For some reason, reliably a call that library is making to pthread_mutex_destroy fails and returns a 16: EBUSY. The documentation says this occurs when "the implementation has detected an attempt to destroy the object referenced by mutex while it is locked or referenced (for example, while being used in a pthread_cond_timedwait() or pthread_cond_wait()) by another thread."

I've put a breakpoint right where the pthread_mutex_destroy() gets called.

a) I don't believe it is locked, since the mutex's state looks like this:
$6 = {__data = {__lock = 0, __count = 0, __owner = 0, __nusers = 4294967293, __kind = 0, __spins = 0, __list = {__prev = 0x0, __next = 0x0}}, 
  __size = '\000' "\375, \377\377\377", '\000' , __align = 0}

And my guess is that __lock = 0 means "unlocked". However, I don't know what __nusers really represents.

b) I don't see any evidence of pthread_cond_wait() or pthread_cond_timedwait(). I got backtraces of all threads running and none were waiting on this mutex.

What could be going on here?

Comment: I don't suppose you setup a [signal-handling thread](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_sigmask) as opposed to the implementation just picking its own ?

Comment: Yes, we do have a signal handling thread. I'm not following, though. Our signal handling thread is what prompts all of this shutdown logic to occur. Does this imply something about why I'm getting the EBUSY?

Comment: I asked because it is conceivable someone is waiting on a condvar married to that mutex. You need to disassociate the mutex from all of the above, ideally in a graceful manner. In the past I've done it by simply broadcasting the condvar signal with a predicate to shut down, then letting the signal thread to terminate (gracefully, of course, not an outright thread-quit). The rest fall like dominos. Whether that is kosher for your rig or application (or if its even kosher at all) is another thing.

Comment: If somebody's waiting on a condvar married to that mutex, then the backtrace of one of the threads should show this at the top of the stack, right? The other threads that are waiting on condvars are all married to other mutexes. Let me know if I've followed you correctly and if what I'm saying makes sense, thanks.

Comment: glibc's pthread code is quite complex, but it does look like `pthread_mutex_destroy()` does return `EBUSY` when the `__nusers` member is non-zero. It doesn't look like your mutex's state is valid though (with the disclaimer that the pthread code is quite complex, so there's a greater than 0 chance I'm wrong about that). Is it possible that some part of your shutdown code is trashing the mutex or freeing the memory block the mutex is in before the destroy call is completed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Obviously, your problem is with `__nusers` member. I would presume, you unlocked the already unlocked mutex somewhere.

Comment: Yes, I do in fact have evidence the mutex got unlocked twice (I was printing statements to that effect). I thought about mentioning it but thought it was innocuous (sorry). Are you saying that each time an unlock() occurs the __nusers member decrements, but that __nusers is signed and it therefore looks like 4294967293? And then pthread_mutex_destroy() returns EBUSY because __nusers is non-zero (like Michael Burr mentioned above)?

Comment: `__nusers` itself is unsigned, but `pthread_mutex_unlock` will decrement it blindly first thing in the morning (http://code.metager.de/source/xref/gnu/glibc/nptl/pthread_mutex_unlock.c), so yes, its value wraps around to 0xfff...