# pthread_mutex_trylock: EBUSY on unused mutex?

Tags: linux, locking, pthreads, mutex, deadlock

Thread is locking up on me.  A trylock is performed first, followed by a blocking lock (this is mostly done so I can log if something else has the lock at this point).  The trylock is failing, and we block forever on the pthread_mutex_lock().  Thing is, the mutex is unused.

Relevant snippet of code:

```
#define LOCK_SESSION(s)                         \
do {                                            \
    int _i_ = pthread_mutex_trylock(&s->s_lock);\
    if (_i_) {                                  \
        logn(LOG_INFO2|LOGF_LOCKS,              \
            "WARNING: Failed to acquire session lock for (%p)->(%p).  (rv: %d:%s)  Fix this.  Going to do a blocking lock.", \
            s, &s->s_lock, _i_, strerror(_i_)); \
        pthread_mutex_lock(&s->s_lock);         \
    }                                           \
    LOG_LOCK(&s->s_lock);                       \
} while (0)
```

gdb output:

```
#0  0x0000003cdc40e334 in __lll_lock_wait () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x0000003cdc4095f3 in _L_lock_892 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#2  0x0000003cdc4094d7 in pthread_mutex_lock () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#3  0x000000000046837c in _fas_make_session_or_acquire (fd=21, shutdown=1) at modules.c:6732
```

Looking at the mutex in question:

```
#3  0x000000000046837c in _fas_make_session_or_acquire (fd=21, shutdown=1) at modules.c:6732
6732    in modules.c
(gdb) p s->s_lock
$17 = {__data = {__lock = 0, __count = 0, __owner = 0, __nusers = 0, __kind = 1, __spins = 0, __list = {__prev = 0x0, __next = 0x0}},
__size = '\000' <repeats 16 times>, "\001", '\000' <repeats 22 times>, __align = 0}
(gdb) p _i_
$18 = 16
```

_i_ holds the return value of pthread_mutex_trylock, which is EAGAIN.
Note that the mutex type (1) is recursive.

So, the trylock fails with an EAGAIN, even though the mutex is entirely unused, and we then go into the black hole of pthread_mutex_lock(), never to return.  I should note this is under extremely heavy usage.

I'm at a loss to explain what's going on here.  Any ideas?

Comment: It may be possible that EBUSY is causede by some thread unlocking the mutex twice, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23750213/pthread-mutex-destroy-why-is-it-returning-ebusy

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.

Unfortunately, in that case the fact that there'd been a double unlock was evident in the '__nusers' attribute, which suggested it had, effectively, gone negative.  In my case, __nusers is 0.